# Rails link_to_if Class Doesnt Display Correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

For the life of me, i cant figure out why this problem is happening.  I used the link_to helper all the time, but iv only used the link_to_if helper a few times, and this time I cant get the link to take a CSS class.

Here's my link

```
<%= link_to_if(step.sequence > 1, raw('<i class="icon-chevron-up"></i>'), url_for(:controller => :test_steps, :action => :update_sequence, :direction => 'up', :id => step.id, :test_script_id => @test_script), { :class => 'btn btn-mini' })%>
```

The image displays, with no link as expected, but the CSS class defined at the end does not, instead it just has no class. This is the same format I use in all my link_to helpers.

Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using link_to_if, only the name --in your case the result of `raw('<i class="icon-chevron-up"></i>')`-- will be returned if the condition fails. All options that would otherwise apply to the link tag will be ignored.

See the [source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/00554568e0625b2e4d4212ab7464f02234f74427/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/url_helper.rb#L452).

Answer (score 0):

Try passing an empty hash as the options argument, so that `{ :class => '...' }` is assigned to the html_options argument.  Untested

```
<%= link_to_if(step.sequence > 1, raw('<i class="icon-chevron-up"></i>'), url_for(:controller => :test_steps, :action => :update_sequence, :direction => 'up', :id => step.id, :test_script_id => @test_script), {}, { :class => 'btn btn-mini' })%>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didnt work. I get : wrong number of arguments (5 for 4)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the **link_to_if** or **link_to_unless** in a span:

```
 %span.pull-right
   = link_to_unless Foo.deleted.empty?, "<i class='icon-white icon-trash'></i> Undelete Foo".html_safe, deleted_foos_path
```

Above code sets a css class (pull-right) on whatever is displayed - full link or just its text.